# Regarding IP on Packet Tracer

Tags: networking, traceroute, packet

I mistakenly gave the IP while configuring the topology in Packet Tracer. How to remove the IP and give the new one? I gave the IP 192.168.1.100 but I need to change it to 192.168.1.0.

Comment: Execute the ip address command with "no" before..e.g. no ip address actualAddress

Answer (score 0):

`Config --> Fastethernet` for the NIC card and `Config --> Global --> (Device name) Static` for other devices.